# How to sort Core Data using the last name, with only a full name available?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data, swift2

I have a `fullName` property in my Core Data entity `Friends`, which has values like:

- John Doe
- Jane Smith
- Joe Bloggs

I want to be able to extract the last name, and sort using these alphabetically, in Swift.

I currently only know how to sort using the full name, like so:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "fullName", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Thanks.

Comment: With a sqlite backend, this isn't possible without just fetching all the records into an array and sorting them yourself. You'll either have to do that or change your data model (unless you're not using sqlite as the backend, in which case you can use a computed property, but you're probably using sqlite as a backend).

Comment: @RobNapier Could you give a code example? I'm currently trying `.sort(by: lastNameASC)`, which I'm trying to write up, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its always better to add the lastName column in the Friends entity. So, that you don't have to write lot of code.

Comment: You're playing in a perfect world where first name and last name are always in one word?

Comment: @FredericP Yeah, I get that (now). Probably was a better idea to have two columns in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Follow.

1) Fetch all record from core data. (Suppose You have get `aryFullname`)

2) Using for loop you can get array only last name as follow.

```
//Define new mutable array aryfinalData
         for i in 0..<aryFullname.count
                {
                  var fullName = aryFullname.ObjectAtindex(i)
                  var fullNameArr = split(fullName) {$0 == " "}
                  var lastName: String? = fullNameArr.count > 1 ? fullNameArr[1] : nil
                  aryfinalData.addObject(lastName)
                 }
```

3) Sort Array as follow.

```
 //  convert NSMutableArray to the Array by using below line of code. 
    let arySort = aryfinalData as AnyObject as! [String]
    var sortedArray = arySort.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
 //  sortedArray is your Final array
```

**Note: This is not a efficient solution but you don't have any solution and I am not sure about the above syntax so take care for the same and do changes if any require.**